# Table with no more than 30k records needs index rebuilding after a handful of inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a table with 20 or so columns. I have approximately 7 non-clustered indexes in that table on the columns that users filter by more often. The active records (those that the users see on their screen) are no more than 700-800. Twice a day a batch job runs and inserts a few records in that table - maybe 30 - 100 - and may update the existing ones as well.

I have noticed that the indexes need rebuilding EVERY time that the batch operation completes. Their fragmentation level doesnt go from 0-1% step by step to say 50%. I have noticed that they go from 0-1% to approx. 99% after the batch operation completes. A zillion of selects can happen on this table between batch operations but i dont think that matters.

Is this normal? i dont think it is. what do you think its the problem here? The indexed columns are mostly strings and floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few changes could easily change fragmentation levels.

- An insert on a page can cause a page split
- Rows can overflow
- Rows can be moved (forward pointers)

You'll have quite wide rows too so your data density (rows per page) is lower. DML on existing rows will cause fragmentation quite quickly if the DML is distributed across many pages

Comment: I see - so in a way this is normal then?

Comment: @Yannis: in this case, I'd say it is expected